# Redirect if no routing in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have routing in my `routes.php` file Like below :

```
Router::connect(
    '/cooks/:country/:state/:city', array('controller' => 'country', 'action' => 'state')
);
```

And when I hit this URL:

```
http://local.test.com/cooks/india/rajasthan/jaipur
```

it works fine, because I have defined the routing in my routes file.

But when I try to access and URL without city name (jaipur) :

```
http://local.test.com/cooks/india/rajasthan/
```

then it returns a 404 code, because I don't have routing in my routes file.

I want it to redirect to some controller action or some other URL, when the city is missing from my URL.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another line to your `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect(
    '/cooks/:country/:state', array('controller' => 'country', 'action' => 'state')
);
```

Comment: But i don't want to add. Any other options.

Comment: @Lakhan if you don't want to serve a 404 and you don't want to define a route what do you want to do? If you hit a URL that doesn't have a defined route it will throw an error!